# virtualbox - existing folder in ubuntu as shared folder

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, git

I have some existing directory in virtualbox running ubuntu, and would like to make this folder a shared folder in virtualbox, so that the host OS, will see it. The end goal is to use git in the host OS running windows, which I think will be easier for me than doing it from ubuntu.
Is it possible to define in virtualbox a shared folder to point to an existing directory ?

Thank you,
Ran

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is. Check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB211nF-Big).

Comment: Hi, I mean that the existing folder is in guest OS (ubuntu running inside virtual box), not in the host OS (windows). I did not find the answer in the links. Thanks